Send http command to chromedriver, it receives the command but not rendering
I'm doing flutter integration test. In this integration test, a chrome driver session will be started by flutter integrationt test framework. I'd like to send some commands to this chromedriver session, like enter image description here; but when i tried this command, i found the page is not changed. The weird thing to me is that when i use get url api, I got the response www.google.com; and if i use takeScreenshot api to get API, I will get a screenshot of google.com; but the page is still not changed and shows something else; I'm sure the session is the same because there's only one session when I query session.
If I start a chromedriver from postman by command, everything works fine; I doubt if flutter integration test framework did something to the chromedriver session but not sure.
